# What's up with Vincent Bold speeding like crazy?

Tags: space-brothers

Vincent Bold and Pico Norton's childhood friend died in a car-related accident (not sure how though). Since then, they both changed and became more determined to become astronauts.

However, Vincent keeps blazing through the roads in his car and always breaking the speed limit, while he keeps repeating that "life is short". How does that work together? I don't really understand his outlook.

He also often says that travel is the most meaningless waste of time, so I suppose it's the reason why he's always in a rush – not just while driving, but also walking, talking and completing tasks. If only he weren't speeding on the road, it'd all make sense. But when his childhood friend died in a car-related accident, I don't get it.